# Añadir un sonido a cada elementos List View en Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, listview

Veréis, tengo una lista de libros que estoy mostrando en un ListView, y me gustaría que al pulsar cada elemento del ListView reproduzca un sonido, en principio me conformaría con un sonido único, aunque me gustaría saber como poder reproducir un sonido por cada elemento, es decir, yo tengo la lista con diferentes libros de Harry Potter (en este caso) y me gustaría que al pulsar cada portada del libro o cada elemento se reproduzca un sonido diferente, lo he intentado con un setOnClickListener pero nada, ni tampoco con un setOnItemClickListener, no reproduce nada, y he comprobado que no fuera por el sonido de mi móvil o el propio archivo, a ver si me podeis ayudar, os dejo el código:

El Activity:

```
package com.eoi.aplicationmenu.books;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.eoi.aplicationmenu.R;
import com.eoi.aplicationmenu.films.FilmActivity;
import com.eoi.aplicationmenu.films.Movie;
import com.eoi.aplicationmenu.films.MovieAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BooksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lvBooks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_books);

        lvBooks = findViewById(R.id.lvBooks);

        Books book1 = new Books();
        book1.setTitle("Harry Potter y la Piedra Filosofal");
        book1.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
        book1.setUrl("https://m.media-amazon.com/images/S/aplus-media/sota/f1abc087-9d36-4c74-9f63-eae7cbd1dc8c.jpg");

        Books book2 = new Books();
        book2.setTitle("Harry Potter y la Cámara Secreta");
        book2.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
        book2.setUrl("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91%2BBwNDpbSL.jpg");

        Books book3 = new Books();
        book3.setTitle("Harry Potter y el Prisionero de Azkaban");
        book3.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
        book3.setUrl("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/910GP4qni2L.jpg");

        Books book4 = new Books();
        book4.setTitle("Harry Potter y el Caliz de Fuego");
        book4.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
        book4.setUrl("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51-bCW%2B8%2BvL._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg");

        Books book5 = new Books();
        book5.setTitle("Harry Potter y la Orden del Fenix");
        book5.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
        book5.setUrl("https://imagessl2.casadellibro.com/a/l/t5/22/9788478887422.jpg");

        Books book6 = new Books();
        book6.setTitle("Harry Potter y el Misterio del Principe");
        book6.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
        book6.setUrl("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51BsPIGtJHL._SX301_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg");

        Books book7 = new Books();
        book7.setTitle("Harry Potter y las Reliquias de la Muerte");
        book7.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
        book7.setUrl("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91Uo5gyDkIL.jpg");

        ArrayList<Books> books = new ArrayList<>();
        books.add(book1);
        books.add(book2);
        books.add(book3);
        books.add(book4);
        books.add(book5);
        books.add(book6);
        books.add(book7);

        BookAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(BooksActivity.this, books);

        lvBooks.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

El Adapter:

```
package com.eoi.aplicationmenu.books;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.eoi.aplicationmenu.R;
import com.eoi.aplicationmenu.films.Movie;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Books> {

    ArrayList<Books> books;

    public BookAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Books> books) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_books, books);
        this.books = books;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()); //Rellenar

        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_books, null);

        ImageView ivPortada = item.findViewById(R.id.ivPortada);
        TextView tvTitulo = item.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
        TextView tvAutor = item.findViewById(R.id.tvAutor);

        Books movie = books.get(position);

        tvTitulo.setText(movie.getTitle());
        tvAutor.setText(movie.getAutor());
        String urlPortada = movie.getUrl();

        Glide.with(getContext()).load(urlPortada).into(ivPortada);

        return item;

    }
}
```

El XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPortada"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitulo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPortada"
        android:text="Este es el título del libro"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAutor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitulo"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPortada"
        android:text="Este es el autor del libro"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

No se si necesitais algún dato más, pero piedad conmigo que soy nuevo en esto de la programación en Android, Java y la programación en general y me voy enterando como buenamente puedo.

Comment: El mismo sonido para todas las filas o cada fila susonido?

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo una explicación más detallada:

1. En primer lugar debes añadir un nuevo atributo a tu clase Books de tipo int, que será el sonido, quedaría de esta forma:

   ```
   public class Books {
       private String title, autor, url;
       private int sound;

       public String getTitle() {
           return title;
       }

       public void setTitle(String title) {
           this.title = title;
       }

       public String getAutor() {
           return autor;
       }

       public void setAutor(String autor) {
           this.autor = autor;
       }

       public String getUrl() {
           return url;
       }

       public void setUrl(String url) {
           this.url = url;
       }

       public int getSound() {
           return sound;
       }

       public void setSound(int sound) {
           this.sound = sound;
       }
   }
   ```
2. En segundo lugar tienes que añadir los sonidos que quieras a la carpeta raw dentro de res, esta es la forma en que se crea:

[image: directorio raw 1]
[image: directorio raw 2]

[image: directorio raw 3]

3. Tras esto, tienes que "settear" el sonido que quieras de la carpeta raw a cada libro dentro de BooksActivity de esta forma:

   ```
   public class BooksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                   setContentView(R.layout.activity_books);

                   ListView lvBooks = findViewById(R.id.lvBooks);

                   Books book1 = new Books();
                   book1.setTitle("Harry Potter y la Piedra Filosofal");
                   book1.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
                   book1.setUrl("https://m.media-amazon.com/images/S/aplus-media/sota/f1abc087-9d36-4c74-9f63-eae7cbd1dc8c.jpg");
                   book1.setSound(R.raw.sound1);

                   Books book2 = new Books();
                   book2.setTitle("Harry Potter y la Cámara Secreta");
                   book2.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
                   book2.setUrl("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91%2BBwNDpbSL.jpg");
                   book2.setSound(R.raw.sound2);

                   Books book3 = new Books();
                   book3.setTitle("Harry Potter y el Prisionero de Azkaban");
                   book3.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
                   book3.setUrl("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/910GP4qni2L.jpg");
                   book3.setSound(R.raw.sound3);

                   Books book4 = new Books();
                   book4.setTitle("Harry Potter y el Caliz de Fuego");
                   book4.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
                   book4.setUrl("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51-bCW%2B8%2BvL._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg");
                   book4.setSound(R.raw.sound4);

                   Books book5 = new Books();
                   book5.setTitle("Harry Potter y la Orden del Fenix");
                   book5.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
                   book5.setUrl("https://imagessl2.casadellibro.com/a/l/t5/22/9788478887422.jpg");
                   book5.setSound(R.raw.sound5);

                   Books book6 = new Books();
                   book6.setTitle("Harry Potter y el Misterio del Principe");
                   book6.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
                   book6.setUrl("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51BsPIGtJHL._SX301_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg");
                   book6.setSound(R.raw.sound6);

                   Books book7 = new Books();
                   book7.setTitle("Harry Potter y las Reliquias de la Muerte");
                   book7.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
                   book7.setUrl("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91Uo5gyDkIL.jpg");
                   book7.setSound(R.raw.sound7);

                   ArrayList<Books> books = new ArrayList<>();
                   books.add(book1);
                   books.add(book2);
                   books.add(book3);
                   books.add(book4);
                   books.add(book5);
                   books.add(book6);
                   books.add(book7);

                   BookAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(BooksActivity.this, books);
                   lvBooks.setAdapter(adapter);
       }
   }
   ```

Cómo habrás visto sólo he añadido un setSound con el sonido de la carpeta que quería añadir en cada libro.

4. Por último, en BookAdapter, tienes que incluir el setOnClickListener sobre la vista que quieres que realice la acción de reproducir el sonido, en este caso yo lo he hecho sobre el fondo del ítem, al cual he asignado un id "itemBackground" (este fondo del ítem es el RelativeLayout que contiene el resto de vistas en item_books.xml). Tras esto tienes que instanciar la clase MediaPlayer con el mismo contexto que has usado para crear la imagen con Glide (getcvontext()) y con el sonido que hemos setteado en la Activity. Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Books> {
       ArrayList<Books> books;

       public BookAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Books> books) {
                   super(context, R.layout.item_books, books);
                   this.books = books;
       }

       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()); //Rellenar

                   View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_books, null);

                   RelativeLayout background = item.findViewById(R.id.itemBackground);

                   ImageView ivPortada = item.findViewById(R.id.ivPortada);
                   TextView tvTitulo = item.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
                   TextView tvAutor = item.findViewById(R.id.tvAutor);

                   Books movie = books.get(position);

                   tvTitulo.setText(movie.getTitle());
                   tvAutor.setText(movie.getAutor());
                   String urlPortada = movie.getUrl();

                   Glide.with(getContext()).load(urlPortada).into(ivPortada);

                   final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), movie.getSound());

                   background.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(View v) {
                                           mediaPlayer.start();
                               }
                   });

                   return item;

       }
   }
   ```

Espero haberme expresado con claridad pero aún así no dudes en preguntar cualquier cosa,

Un saludo,

Comment: ¿De donde sale el "R.id.background" del Adapter? Y otra cosa, ¿donde pone context lo debería dejar tal cual? Me reitero en que estoy super verde jajajaja

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, mira a ver si te sirve!

Comment: vale, parece que lo voy entendiendo, la parte que no entiendo es la del background, tengo que crear un item background en el XML o es un atributo del RelativeLayout? Ahí es donde tengo la mayor duda creo, que no se de donde sale

Comment: itemBackground es un id que he asignado al RelativeLayout de tu ítem_books.xml, al igual que tu ImageView de portada tiene el id ivPortada, por ejemplo. De hecho si quieres y para no liarte, en lugar de asignar el setOnClickListener a la "tarjeta" de fondo o background, asígnaselo a ivPortada:

ivPortada.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
...

De esta forma verás que al clickear sobre la imagen, se reproduce el sonido, lo único que cambia es la vista en la que clickeas.

Comment: Juraria que lo tengo igual pero no me lo reproduce, no se si el formato tiene que ver, tengo los sonidos en .wav, ¿influye en algo?

Comment: Yo también, si quieres puedes enviarme el proyecto a rmedina.dev@gmail.com o subirlo a Github y le echaré un ojo.

Comment: https://github.com/Iesedobleac/AplicationMenu aquí te lo dejo recién subido, tiene más clases y tal ya que esto viene de un menú, si tienes problemas para identificar los archivos dimelo.

Comment: ¿Puedes subir el proyecto entero? De esa forma puedo compilarlo y ver mejor dónde te está fallando. De momento he copiado y pegado las tres clases de los libros, sus xml y los audios y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Vale, dame un momento y te lo envío al correo!

Comment: Creo que te lo mandé bien, confirmame que lo has recibido por si acaso :)

Comment: Buenos días, lo he recibido, lo he probado tal cual me lo has mandado y funciona. Ten en cuenta que suena cuando pulsas las imágenes de la portada del listado de libros. De igual forma comprueba que tienes el sonido multimedia del terminal encendido.

Comment: esto es rarísimo, lo he probado tal cual el que te pase y no suena, lo he probado en otro móvil y al pulsar las imágenes se cierra la aplicación :(

Comment: Ignoro el por qué ayer me dejaba ejecutar los archivos .wav, pero al parecer Android Studio no da soporte para los audios con esa extensión:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

Prueba si el libro 7 funciona al clickear la imagen, que es el que tiene el audio en formato .mp3.

Comment: que va, no lo reproduce, ni ese ni ninguno...

Comment: ¿Entonces no hay ninguna otra solución?

Comment: Es extraño, lo he estado mirando y tu código funciona en todos mis dispositivos, no he encontrado nada más.

Comment: y lo reproduce al pulsar la imagen de la portada? Es que a ver si yo mismo estoy haciendo algo mal...

Comment: Así es, como consejos, prueba otras aplicaciones a ver si el volumen multimedia funciona, mira el log a ver si te da algún error aunque la app no se cierre, prueba en otros dispositivos y cambia el evento del onClickListener para que recaiga sobre otra vista.

Comment: Debería darse por válida esta respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Mi amigo..  concuerdo con lo que dice Rodrigo.. te explicare

en tu activity

```
Books book1 = new Books();
        book1.setTitle("Harry Potter y la Piedra Filosofal");
        book1.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
        book1.setUrl("https://m.media-amazon.com/images/S/aplus-media/sota/f1abc087-9d36-4c74-9f63-eae7cbd1dc8c.jpg");
```

añade una variable mas.. por ejemplo algo como esto

```
Books book1 = new Books();
        book1.setTitle("Harry Potter y la Piedra Filosofal");
        book1.setAutor("J.K. Rowling");
        book1.setUrl("https://m.media-amazon.com/images/S/aplus-media/sota/f1abc087-9d36-4c74-9f63-eae7cbd1dc8c.jpg");
book1.setSonido("1");
```

en tu clase Books

```
Books movie = books.get(position);
```

agrega los get y set para Sonido

esta nueva variable nos ayudara para identificar que sonido quieres.

digamos ..

```
si es 1 que suene el sonido1.. sino el sonido2 etc
```

ahora en el Adapter

añade la condición ya mencionada.

```
String Sonido = movie.getSonido();
```

validación

```
   if(Sonido.equal("1"))
    {
    //ejecuta el sonido
    MediaPlayer mp;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,


                R.raw.tono_1);
                mp.start();
}
else
{
//ejecuta otro sonido o nada. 
}
```

la carpeta raw la puedes crear de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no, creo que ahora me he liado más ya que no se donde tengo que meter cada linea de código que me has escrito, osea algunas si, pero en otras me pierdo